# Host html with javascript dependencies on node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

My question is: Whether one can host an entire website along with JavaScript dependencies on node.js with/without express or other frameworks.

The JavaScript will contain html specific calls like using the window object to create a new window or post messages to other windows/web workers . I've had a bit of experience running JavaScript but have no experience running node and I've searched a lot trying to find a solid answer.

If this does require using a framework all I have to say is that this functionality should be already included in the vanilla node build from day 0 and why it is not confuses me.

Here is a basic HTML code example of what I want to run

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
let window = window.open()

 window.onload = function (){
  window.postmessage({hello:"world"})
  }
 </script>

 <script src="./ImageResource.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Q/A

"Why not just open a page manually and communicate with it using node"
I have a entire project built in vanilla JavaScript and do not wish to convert it to node compliant code (not yet) .

Disclaimers:
If you feel this question has been answered properly on another thread please instead of negative reviews I ask that you link it to me so I may question whether or not I should take down my thread for deprecation . Thank you have a nice day !.

Comment: I think it is good to follow how the majority does. In my experience, it could be wrong however, Javascript code in a certain framework cannot always be embedded in HTML code.

Comment: When it comes to just serving up static pages, it's probably better to use a regular web server like Apache for this. You won't be using any node.js functionality anyway. But if you really wanted to, serving up static pages from node.js should also be trivial.

Comment: Thanks so much guys I appreciate the comments :) . If I don't find a solid answer I will definitely be switching languages for sure .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  Express and what not are all built in JavaScript after all.

But, why would you want to?  Express isn't generally considered a heavyweight framework. 
 It doesn't impose much on you, and it utilizes the underlying Node.js-built-in HTTP request/response objects.  It's a good tool in general.

In any case, it doesn't sound like you need Node.js at all for your project.  Any web server will do.  Node.js is generally used for server-side work.  It isn't needed to just host your web page.

Comment: This is just for testing at the moment but I want to know I can host applications as such so in the future I can make projects that run client side without relying on the server to move it . Also a big plus is having it all in the same language otherwise I would have just gone python or something for learning experience.

Comment: @static660 If you're running your HTML client-side, you still don't need a server (usually).  Just open the HTML page directly.

Comment: If you use post message it forces you by cross domain policy. I also have other things that force me to run it on a server instead . If I didn't have to I wouldn't.